# Получение данных из web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

В web.config добавил кастомную секцию

```
<packaging>
    <qtytoshow value="8"/>
</packaging>
```

А для удобства получения данных сделал конфигурационный класс.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("qtytoshow", IsRequired = true)]
public QuantityConfiguration Quantity
{
    get { return (QuantityConfiguration) base["qtytoshow"]; }
    set { base["qtytoshow"] = value; }
}

public class QuantityConfiguration : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
    public int QtyToShow
    {
        get { return (int) base["value"]; }
        set { base["value"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Resharper подсвечивает следующую ошибку

```
Error   67  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

И указывает на участки кода `(int) base["value"];` и `base["qtytoshow"]`. Помогите понять, почему здесь он указывает ошибку, а в другом файле точно такой же конфигурации ее нет?

Другой фаил конфигурации

```
[ConfigurationProperty("printer", IsRequired = true)]
public PrinterConfiguration Printer
{
    get { return (PrinterConfiguration) base["printer"]; }
    set { base["printer"] = value;  }
}

public class PrinterConfiguration : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("address", IsRequired = false)]
        public string Address
    {
        get { return (string)base["address"]; }
        set { base["address"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что нужно не забывать указывать наследование от класса ConfigurationSection для корневого класса.